# How to keep multindex while converting between json/csv to dataframae

Tags: python, json, pandas

[image][image]

The top image is the original dataframe

The bottom image is the dataframe after I went dataframe -> Json -> dataframe

Converting back and forth form dataframe to json removes the multiindex. Is there a way to prevent this or get it back to a multiindex.

*also sorry for the naked dataframe I cant get IPython.display to work and I don't know why -- it is updated. If anyone has a solution for this  also help is greatly apricated*

Comment: json doesn't support tuple key, why do you want json?

Comment: In reality I don't care how it is saved - I just want to be able to save the dataframe to a file format that will keep the multidex intact. I also tried using .csv and .xlsx but they did not keep the multidex either.

Comment: Then use some binary form, for example [pd.to_pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html). `to_csv` and `to_excel` would also work if you `read_csv` and `read_excel` with `header=2` param.

Answer (score 0):

After reading it from JSON, you got a `new_df`. And now you need to convert the columns to `multiindex`

```py
json_data = old_df.to_json()
new_df = pd.read_json(json_data)

# Str to Tuple
col = map(eval,new_df.columns)

new_df.columns= pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col)

print(new_df)
```